# d3, updating multiple paths

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

The following code has multiple paths on a single d3.js plot. I have the initial plot working, displaying the data set `d0`. It looks like this on load:

[image: Displayed when loaded]

I would like to display the data in `d1` when the button is pressed, so it should look like this:

[image: What it should look like after pressing the button]

What currently happens is...nothing. No errors in the console, no change to the display, and no change to the DOM (that I can see?).

I've been through a dozen code examples and tutorials and just don't see what's going wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated (particularly if with an explanation of what I'm conceptually missing). Thanks!

```js
var d0 = [{
    id: "A",
    values: [{
      x: .25,
      y: .9
    }, {
      x: .75,
      y: 1
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "B",
    values: [{
      x: .25,
      y: .5
    }, {
      x: .8,
      y: .4
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "C",
    values: [{
      x: .1,
      y: .1
    }, {
      x: .9,
      y: .1
    }]
  }
]


var d1 = [{
    id: "A",
    values: [{
      x: 0,
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: 1,
      y: 1
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "B",
    values: [{
      x: 0,
      y: .5
    }, {
      x: 1,
      y: .5
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "C",
    values: [{
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }, {
      x: 1,
      y: 0
    }]
  }
]

var svg = d3.select("svg")

var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 80,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
}
var width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right
var height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom

g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

var scaleX = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).domain([0, 1])
var scaleY = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain([0, 1])

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(scaleX));

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(scaleY))

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return scaleX(d.x)
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return scaleY(d.y)
  });

var lineg = g.selectAll(".lineg")
  .data(d0)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "lineg");

lineg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.values)
  })

function update() {

  var i = g.selectAll(".lineg")
    .data(d1)

  i.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "lineg")

  i.exit()
    .remove()

  g.selectAll(".line")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return line(d.values)
    })
}
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
<br/>
<button onclick="update()">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every SVG element that you call `.data` or `.datum` on has an internal reference to a data object. In your update call, you updated the data of the `g` elements that held the lines, but never of the lines themselves.

I was able to do that with the following code:

```
i.select(".line")
  .datum(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.values)
  })
```

Here, starting from the newly selected groups `i`, which you already gave the correct data, I select the line, and then pass it the datum object from the `g` directly, through the function. That way, the datum object gets updated, and calling `line(d.values)` now actually uses entries from `d1` instead of `d0`.

```js
var d0 = [{
    id: "A",
    values: [{
      x: .25,
      y: .9
    }, {
      x: .75,
      y: 1
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "B",
    values: [{
      x: .25,
      y: .5
    }, {
      x: .8,
      y: .4
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "C",
    values: [{
      x: .1,
      y: .1
    }, {
      x: .9,
      y: .1
    }]
  }
]


var d1 = [{
    id: "A",
    values: [{
      x: 0,
      y: 1
    }, {
      x: 1,
      y: 1
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "B",
    values: [{
      x: 0,
      y: .5
    }, {
      x: 1,
      y: .5
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "C",
    values: [{
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }, {
      x: 1,
      y: 0
    }]
  }
]

var svg = d3.select("svg")

var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 80,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
}
var width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right
var height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom

g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

var scaleX = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]).domain([0, 1])
var scaleY = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain([0, 1])

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(scaleX));

g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(scaleY))

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return scaleX(d.x)
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return scaleY(d.y)
  });

var lineg = g.selectAll(".lineg")
  .data(d0)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "lineg");

lineg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return line(d.values)
  })

function update() {
  var i = g.selectAll(".lineg")
    .data(d1)

  i.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "lineg")

  i.exit()
    .remove()

  i.select(".line")
    .datum(function(d) {
      return d;
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return line(d.values)
    })
}
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
<br/>
<button onclick="update()">Change</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works well. I notice that you use select() instead of selectAll(). Is the reason why selectAll() doesn't work because datum() requires a single element?

Comment: Yes, then you should wrap the element in an array of length 1 and use `.data` I think